# How to set the language to use for AngularDart Material components?

Tags: angular-material, angular-dart

By default, date picker, and form validation messages are in english. 
I need to have them in french. 
I can't find any documentation... :'(

Answer (score 0):

[Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-locale-code) states:

> By default, the MAT_DATE_LOCALE injection token will use the existing LOCALE_ID locale code from @angular/core. If you want to override it, you can provide a new value for the MAT_DATE_LOCALE token:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR'},
  ],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

> It's also possible to set the locale at runtime using the `setLocale` method of the `DateAdapter`.

Another option may be found at https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID.

Answer (score 0):

package:intl is used which you can see documentation here: https://pub.dev/packages/intl

The translations itself aren't bundled. They would need to be sent to a translation service itself.